# The square of a standard Normal random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

I am having a bit of trouble with this:

Let $U=Z^2$ where Z is a standard Normal random variable with pdf:

$$f_z(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}}$$

I want to use the inversion method but have thus far only learned to use this when functions are strictly increasing or decreasing. Since a standard normal distribution function is strictly increasing and then strictly decreasing I thought perhaps I could find some way to use this method.

I have the final answer as $f_u(u)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{u}}e^{\frac{-u}{2}}$ for $u>0$

But I am not very comfortable with the process of getting to that answer. I used a bit of a walk through and made some assumptions about what was happening.

Could anyone help me understand how I should use the above information to reach this answer?

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597321/characteristic-function-of-normal-random-variable-squared

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71537/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to get the answer using more basic principles.

$$f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}, \quad -\infty < z < \infty.$$  This much you already know.  Then $$\begin{align*} F_U(u) &= \Pr[U \le u] \\ &= \Pr[Z^2 \le u] \\ &= \Pr[-\sqrt{u} \le Z \le \sqrt{u}] \\ &= \Pr[Z \le \sqrt{u}] - \Pr[Z \le -\sqrt{u}] \\ &= F_Z(\sqrt{u}) - F_Z(-\sqrt{u}), \end{align*}$$  where $F_Z(z)$ is the cumulative distribution function for $Z$.  Now differentiate with respect to $u$, taking care to use the chain rule:  $$f_U(u) = \frac{f_Z(\sqrt{u})}{2\sqrt{u}} - \frac{f_Z(-\sqrt{u})}{-2\sqrt{u}} = \frac{f_Z(\sqrt{u}) + f_Z(-\sqrt{u})}{2\sqrt{u}}.$$  Now substitute back into the density for $Z$: $$f_U(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{2e^{-u/2}}{2\sqrt{u}} = \frac{e^{-u/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi u}}, \quad u > 0. $$  The distribution of $U$ is known as the chi-square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.

Answer (score -2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{\expo{-z^{2}/2}}{\root{2\pi}}\delta\pars{u - z^{2}}\,\dd z}
=2\Theta\pars{u}\,\frac{\expo{-u/2}}{\root{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{\delta\pars{z - \root{u}}}{2\root{u}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\Theta\pars{u}\,\frac{u^{-1/2}\ \expo{-u/2}}{\root{2\pi}}}
\end{align}

Comment: This relies on the detailed handling of change of variables in delta distributions (in Laurent Schwartz's sense, not the probability theory one), which physicists use a lot (sometimes rather carelessly) and mathematicians not so much. So, yes, this could be completed so as to reach the status of a mathematical answer, but such a task is not done here (not to mention that the détour is not needed, see the other answer for the details of the fully rigorous, standard, approach). _(ed ajf)_