# $X^2$, when $X\sim N(0,1)$ : $2\frac{\operatorname{d}F_X(\sqrt{y})}{\operatorname{d} y}$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, chi-squared

I was reading this:
[Characteristic function of Normal random variable squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597321/characteristic-function-of-normal-random-variable-squared)

And there is a step, where I do not manage to understand the equality marked as "$\stackrel{???}{=}$"

We have 
$$ F_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right)= \int_{-\infty}^\sqrt{y} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \operatorname{d}t$$
and the pdf is 
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\operatorname{d}F_Y(y}{\operatorname{d} y}=2\frac{\operatorname{d}F_X(\sqrt{y})}{\operatorname{d} y} \stackrel{???}{=} 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-\frac{y}{2}} \left( \frac{1}{2} y^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}y^{\frac{1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}  \Bbb{I}_{[0,+\infty)}(y) 
$$

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at the Leibniz integral rule https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dy}F_X(\sqrt y)=f_X(\sqrt y)\frac{d}{dy}(\sqrt y)$$ , where $f_X$ is the pdf of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's differentiate $F_X$ with respect to its argument $\sqrt{y}$, giving $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp -\frac{(\sqrt{y})^2}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp -\frac{y}{2}$. Now we use the chain rule to get the derivative with respect to $y$ instead, by multiplying by $\frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{y}=\frac{1}{2}y^{-1/2}$.